# How to make Tampermonkey userscript execute before other scripts of page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I need to login a web page that forced to use IE.

The page looks like the following code.

```html
<Script Language="javascript">
alert("Please use IE to login!");
window.opener = null;
window.close();
</Script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I want to use Chrome to login, so I have to prevent this script from closing the window.
I have tried using Tampermonkey script, but my script always executed later than the script of page.

The metadata `// @run-at  document-start` doesn't seem to work.

Below is the code I have tried.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://localhost:8080/666/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=undefined.localhost
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

// reference: https://github.com/jspenguin2017/Snippets/blob/master/onbeforescriptexecute.html
(function() {
    'use strict';
    
    const Event = class {
        constructor(script, target) {
            this.script = script;
            this.target = target;

            this._cancel = false;
            this._replace = null;
            this._stop = false;
        }

        preventDefault() {
            this._cancel = true;
        }
        stopPropagation() {
            this._stop = true;
        }
        replacePayload(payload) {
            this._replace = payload;
        }
    };

    let callbacks = [];
    window.addBeforeScriptExecuteListener = (f) => {
        if (typeof f !== "function") {
            throw new Error("Event handler must be a function.");
        }
        callbacks.push(f);
    };
    window.removeBeforeScriptExecuteListener = (f) => {
        let i = callbacks.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (callbacks[i] === f) {
                callbacks.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    };

    const dispatch = (script, target) => {
        if (script.tagName !== "SCRIPT") {
            return;
        }

        const e = new Event(script, target);

        if (typeof window.onbeforescriptexecute === "function") {
            try {
                window.onbeforescriptexecute(e);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }else{
            console.log("window.onbeforescriptexecute no defined");
        }

        for (const func of callbacks) {
            if (e._stop) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                func(e);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }

        if (e._cancel) {
            script.textContent = "";
            script.remove();
        } else if (typeof e._replace === "string") {
            script.textContent = e._replace;
        }
    };
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        window.close = ()=>{return;};
        for (const m of mutations) {
            for (const n of m.addedNodes) {
                dispatch(n, m.target);
            }
        }
    });
    observer.observe(document, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
    });
    
    //example
    (() => {
            "use strict";
            window.onbeforescriptexecute = (e) => {
                // You should check if textContent exists as this property is
                // buggy sometimes
                if (!e.script.textContent) {
                    return;
                }

                // Prevent execution of a script
                if (e.script.textContent.includes("window.close()")) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //e.stopPropagation();
                }

                // Change the code that runs
                if (e.script.textContent.includes("console.log")) {
                    // Original payload is e.script.textContent, you can
                    // manipulate it however you want, just pass the final
                    // payload to e.replacePayload when you are done
                    e.replacePayload("console.log(2);");
                    // Later event handlers can override your payload, you
                    // can call e.stopPropagation to make sure the current
                    // payload is applied
                }
            };
    })();
})();
```

Comment: I have to say that I am really happy to see a question in the [userscript] tag where the OP has actually tried to solve the problem, and even put such an effort. I follow this tag and this is rare, kudos to you.

Comment: You need to enable instant injection in the options for Tampermonkey, then your script will run earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that by virtue of listening for any event, your callback will execute after the document parses. This is because events are invoked asynchronously, and document parsing along with any `<script>` are executed in one go - as if it was one continuous JavaScript function. Even if any events are triggered, afaik the browser only gets to them once it's done parsing.

In addition, the event you're listening for is not even supported by Chrome, not officially.

When trying to deal with nasty stuff like what you encountered, you need to override whatever functions is the nasty code using and change them to break it. I'd start with wrapping `window.close`:

```
window.close = function() { console.log("Nice try, but no"); }
```

In addition, consider if you can figure out how does it detect IE and fake IE. For example, if it uses `navigator.userAgent`, you need to change that. Take note that some properties are not assignable because they are getter/setter. If you just assign `navigator.userAgent = "totally IE"`, it's not gonna change. But you can change the setter:

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, "userAgent", {get:()=>"I am IE! For real!", set:()=>{}})
```

And there you go, totally IE. If it just uses userAgent, you can also make use of some extension that is designed specifically for faking user agents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My script can run earlier than the script of page after instant injection enabled.

Comment: Yes, but my point is, the events will not. You can actually test that fairly easily by logging when they fire (if they fire at all). Did you try to override `window.close` as I suggested?